# Keras input name of a named layer

Tags: input, keras

If we do create a layer as:

Embedding(name='a')

then the network expects named input as 'a_input'.

How to specify the input name? (And still have a Layer object)

Comment: Are you using the Functional or Sequential API?

Comment: I would love the sequential api (for multiinput model). I know that by functional API I know that I can do myinp = Input(name='a') and then Embedding(...)(myinp), but then it cannot be added to sequential model.